# Show "No Results" in searchBar if the text does not match the existing data

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a `searchBar`, where user can search for his channels. Main question is, how it possible to do, so `when user tap some text which is not match the data which he have and then it will show "No results"` like on this photo: [image]

At the moment, if user tap correct text, which match the data, it shows the data. Here is my code:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        guard !searchText.isEmpty else { filteredActiveState = activeStates; tableView.reloadData(); return }

        searching = true
        //typeView.isHidden = true
        
        if filteredActiveState.isEmpty {
            typeView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            typeView.isHidden = false
            typeText.text = "No Results - try other terms"
        }

        filteredActiveState = activeStates.filter({ titleName -> Bool in
            return titleName.title!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.isHidden = true
        channelLbl.isHidden = false
        searchButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
        typeView.isHidden = true
        //searchBar.endEditing(true)
        //searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        typeView.isHidden = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Your code isn't working? What's happening? You might want to show/hide the view after you did `activeStates.filter()`, no?

Comment: Maybe, not sure. Code is working, but "No results" showing every time, need only when user enter text which is not match the data

Comment: So use the right condition: Is search text empty? Is the filteredActiveState after the filter empty or not? Test the condition in the right order, then after yopu might factorize if needed, but at least it would be clear and working

Comment: Maybe you don't understand correctly. I want, so: User taps "name of class" and if it's exits, it will show. And the main question is: If user taps "fdkfskn" for example, and it should show "no results"

Comment: I think I understood as I previously said: `var hide = true; guard !searchText.isEmpty else { filteredActiveState = activeStates; typeView.isHidden = hide tableView.reloadData(); return }  filteredActiveState = activeStates.filter { ... } if filteredActiveState.isEmpty { hide = false } else { hide = true } typeView.isHidden = hide`

Comment: When I delete all text, the view is not hidden. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

So, according to your last comment you handled it, but forgot one more thing? to set `searching = false`

in this part of code, f.e.:

```
guard !searchText.isEmpty else { 
   searching = false
   filteredActiveState = activeStates
   tableView.reloadData()
   return
}
```

and in other places where it needs